# Unable to find bundled Java version when installing flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Unable to find bundled Java version when installing flutter.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems to be only for old Android Studio versions. Does this cause any issues?

Comment: It's seems the problem from android studio, I'll try to uninstall and install it again...

Comment: Does it cause problems when you just ignore it? Not everything is required what `flutter doctor` checks.

Comment: problem solved bye deleting older version of android studio folder and install a new one....

Comment: Faced the same issue, and agree with @QusaySaad that deleting the older version and installing the new one have fixed my issue.

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67845759/2457493

Answer (score 0):

If you check closer, there are 3 versions of Android Studio installed: version 1.2, version 1.5 and version 3.0.

Among the 3 versions, it seems that the 2 older version were the one's getting those error. And for the record it was [mentioned in the documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#android-ide) that you only needed the latest version of Android Studio. It means that you only need one version of Android Studio.

> Before trying this, make sure that you’re on the latest version of
> Android Studio and the Flutter plugins.

Also, here is a [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15514#issuecomment-373329235) that was filed for this issue as reference.