# Unable to find bundled Java version on Flutter

Tags: java, flutter

I have `Android Studio version 3.0`. When I use the command `flutter doctor` it shows me the following:

> Unable to find bundled Java version

My current Java version is `(build 1.8.0_131-b11)` on Windows 10.

I don't have any older versions of Android Studio on my computer.

Comment: This GitHub-issue response solved it for me: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502#issuecomment-1383215722

Answer (score 416):

### For **Mac** Users:

Set the `JAVA_HOME` path by following [this article](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#what-is-usrlibexecjava-home) and then  apply the following commands:

#### For the JetBrains Runtime "Android Studio Electric Eel"

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr
ln -s ../jbr jdk
ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
```

Then go to the *Finder* and search for *Android Studio*:

1. Right click -> *Show Package Contents*
2. Open the *contents* folder, then create new folder called `jre`
3. Copy the contents of the JetBrainsRuntime folder and paste it into the `jre` folder

`flutter doctor -v` should work now!

#### Other versions

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
ln -s ../jre jdk
ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
```

Then you can run `flutter doctor -v`

---

### For Mac users who are using the `JetBrains Toolbox`:

Set the `JAVA_HOME` path following [the article](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#what-is-usrlibexecjava-home).

After that, change `username` to your macOS username and run:

```
cd /Users/username/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7583922/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre
ln -s ../jre jdk
ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

flutter doctor -v
```

If you're still facing the issue, you can try this workaround:

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents
ln -s jbr jre
```

Comment: just add a bit info. from that mkyong.com article, you only need to execute the command from 2.1 2.2 and 2.3 then continue to execute the command from Nalawala above. it works!

Comment: also work for me. just note. JRE folder you can find at cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre

Comment: creating sym-links (as suggested in this answer) will break it once again when you update Android Studio.
Better just follow steps 3 + 4 in the linked article from mkyong.com

Comment: Worked perfectly on Android Studio Preview, with slight change to command to account for beta version "cd /Applications/Android\ Studio\ Preview.app/Contents/jre"

Comment: Did everything suggested here but was still having the error ! Uninstalling Android Studio Preview solved the problem for me.

Comment: I followed everything except that I couldn't find "jre" folder, it was "jbr" for me. issue was fixed when I renamed the folder to "jre"

Comment: @Texv instead of rename, create a link by "ln -s jbr jre", otherwise "Android Studio Preview" can not be launched.

Comment: An update for MAC users running Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1, new location to set JAVA_HOME should be '/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home' 
reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43237101

Comment: 'sudo ln -s jbr jre' was giving me 'ln: jre: Operation not permitted' so I just copied the jbr folder and renamed it jre

Comment: If your not permitted go here https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Comment: Thank you so much it is working on MacBook Pro M1 Pro Android Studio Electric eel

Comment: I pasted this in my zshenv file: export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home and then did all the steps under the "For Mac Users" section above. Installed Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 with macOS Monterey. Works now, thanks.

Comment: God bless the internet... Attention for anyone using newer versions of Mac btw, even 'sudo ln -s jbr jre' will fail because there is a new security setting where you actually have to go in and grant terminal permission to edit other applications.

Answer (score 402):

**Right approach**

In short and simple, the best approach to fix this issue is by upgrading your Android Studio and Flutter to latest versions, in order to avoid any potential issues (e.g. patching) in future.

**Original answer**

For those having these issues with the latest Android Studio - Electric Eel version, and other canaries and preview releases, note that the bundled `jre` directory in the Android Studio installation folder is now renamed to `jbr`

To resolve this, just create a sym link `jre` -> `jbr` and Flutter won't complain.

On Linux

```
cd ~/android-studio/ && ln -s jbr jre
```

Windows (check installation folder)

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
mklink /D "jre" "jbr"
```

or

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path .\jre -Target .\jbr
```

Mac OS

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents
ln -s jbr jre
```

---

Note that if you are running a preview release, and depending on your OS, the default installation directory might be different, e.g. on Linux it would be

```
~/android-studio-preview/
```

In either case, you can check the installation directory by running

```
flutter doctor -v
```

---

Also, in case if you run with permissions issues, you can try running the command with admin privileges, depending on your OS.

For example on Mac/Linux, you can just run the same command with `sudo` and it should work, additionally on Mac, you'll have to configure the **Disk Access** permissions, depends on your version, but most probably can be found under:

`Settings - Privacy & Security - Full Disk Access - Terminal`

Comment: Is there any source or comment on the directory name change by the dev team?
Been pulling my hair for the last hour reinstalling and browsing the directories trying to figure it out what was wrong, thanks

Comment: bro, operation not permitted on mac to create a symlink between jbr and jre, please help

Comment: @VanditShah give the terminal full disk access at `settings>privacy & security>full disk access>terminal` and then call the command with `sudo`

Comment: On Linux if you are part of the beta / preview program of Android Studio, then the command is `cd ~/android-studio-preview/ && ln -s jbr jre`. This startled me, because I have the regular directory and your command didn't fix it. Then I realized I'm using a Preview version. You can add that.

Comment: When I try to do this in AS Terminal it complains: ```PS C:\Program Files\android\android studio> mklink /D "jre" "jbr"
mklink : The term 'mklink' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mklink /D "jre" "jbr"``` - help!

Comment: @Sam try `New-Item -ItemType...`, as the `mklink` is a command in CMD. If that doesn't work maybe just run the above in Power Shell or CMD :)

Comment: works fine, but I'd like to know more about what happens if you create link instead of common folder which Android Studio gives you from scratch, any hidden rocks?

Comment: On Windows, flutter doctor was throwing this error with latest Android Studio i.e. Electric Eel | 2022.1.1.

However for me, jre folder already existed under C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio which contained just one file \jre\bin\.marker.

I renamed the existing jre folder into jre_old and afterwards created the symbolic link through below command. problem fixed !


cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

mklink /D "jre" "jbr"

Comment: @VanditShah Another solution for those using a restricted company computer or getting "operation not permitted," install [Android Studio Dolphin](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive), the previous version of Android Studio (accept the terms at the bottom of page). During installation, it'll ask if you want to uninstall new version during installation.

Comment: Windows solution worked, but my Android Studio was installed with Jetbrains Toolbox and the location was different. To see the actual Android Studio path run `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: This helped me a lot of time. PS. for those who are getting "Access Denied" error on windows by running `mklink /D "jre" "jbr"`, just run CMD as Administrator.

Comment: if you're on Linux and installed Android studio via the JetBrains Toolbox app, the path you're looking for will be something like `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/221.6008.13.2211.9477386`. The last directory name could be different

Comment: @eja Before doing that, we should have to rename `jre` dir to another name, say, `jreOld`, otherwise, **CMD says that it cannot create symbolic link if the same (`jre`) dir is there**.
then, we can run command given in answer above (for Windows)!

Comment: ln: jre: Operation not permitted

On Mac

Comment: Try giving the terminal the required permissions and run the same with `sudo`
I suppose you the needed permissions are Disk Access in `Settings - Privacy & Security - Full Disk Access - Terminal`

Comment: This breaks Android Studio patching. Is there a way to point flutter to jbr without making changes to jre folder?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This issue bothered me for a couple of hours. Finally resolved.

Comment: Flutter 3.7.7 (and possibly earlier recent versions) look for the JRE under `jbr`, making workarounds like this unnecessary. Thus one solution is to upgrade to a more recent Flutter version.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! One very minor clarification, on a Mac, the **Disk Access Permissions** are in the **Mac Settings**, not the **Android Studio Settings**.

Comment: God bless the internet... Attention for anyone using newer versions of Mac btw, even 'sudo ln -s jbr jre' will fail because there is a new security setting where you actually have to go in and grant terminal permission to edit other applications.

Comment: helpfull answer

Answer (score 208):

For Windows users:

Go to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`, then copy the contents of **jbr** and paste the contents into the **jre** folder.

Run `flutter doctor` again and it will solve the problem.

(I'm running Android studio 2022.1)

Comment: Delete the jre folder and change the environment variable to jbr. It works for me even the flutter doctor complains.

Comment: im using android studio 2022.1.1 and this answer works for me.

Comment: This breaks Android Studio patching

Comment: When I try to install the Android Studio patch I get a fatal error saying that jre/bin/.marker file was not found. To resolve, I removed the symbolic link, created the jre/bin/.marker folders and empty file. This allows installation to complete. Then I applied the symbolic link fix again to fix flutter. Not ideal... This is on Windows 10

Answer (score 83):

**For Windows:**
If you are using windows go to this directory C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio and check older Android Studio folders are exist if exist  delete those. it will work.

Comment: The older one is one with only the JRE folder like @Neail pointed it out. The one with the smaller number

Answer (score 57):

**For Mac Users**

Make sure you have installed java and set the java_home path, you can use homebrew for that.

If you installed **Android Studio Electric Eel** Follow the following step

1. Go to your Applications folder.
2. Search for Android Studio.app. (`flutter doctor -v` also has an `Android Studio` entry which will show you the app location)
3. Right click and select Show Package Content.
4. Navigate into the Content Folder that opens.
5. Use your terminal to cd into that folder and then enter the command below and everything should be solved

```
ln -s jbr jre
```

The command above creates a symbolic link

The symbolic link also works on Ubuntu.

Comment: Why this this happen with Electric Eel suddenly? Never had this problem before, just recently.

Comment: @CsabaToth well I think Android Studio was built on JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA software, which uses its own version of openjdk called Jetbrains runtime(jbr). So I think in the new version of android studio, maybe they might have switched to using Jetbrains jrb.

Comment: here is the video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ry_Zyyq-ZDQ&ab_channel=MdShihabUddin

Comment: I used brew to install Android Studio. `cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/ && ln -s jbr jre`

Comment: For users who use `toolbox`, `flutter doctor -v` will show you the `Android Studio` app location. Then do the above.

Comment: You have to add permission privacy setting for terminal to execute ln. https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Answer (score 34):

In my case, I am using macOS, there was a copy of Android Studio Preview in my Downloads folder. I just deleted that Android Studio Preview file and the error was gone.

Answer (score 27):

Those on the Beta Versions of MAC OS Beta, Xcode Beta, Android Studio Preview.

Just ensure your path ways are correct to the Applications files for Flutter.

To fix JAVA Bundle for Android Studio Preview do this:

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio\ Preview.app/Contents/jre

ln -s ../jre jdk

ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

flutter doctor -v
```

Comment: cd: no such file or directory: /Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jre

Comment: no jre folder in Android Studio Preview.app. I solved it and post my solution below for Android Studio Preview

Answer (score 19):

I was getting error as below,

[image]

Execute below steps to resolve this issue,

1. Visit Google folder in user directory
   [image]
2. Delete the AndroidStudio4.1 directory ( For which I was getting error )
   [image]

Run "flutter doctor" again. My problem was fixed

Answer (score 17):

I have recently encountered the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

After searching a lot I have fixed this issue by removing the Android Studio path from the Flutter config by running below mention command.

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=
```

Solution:

[image: Solution]

Comment: make sure no spaces in the path of the directory

Comment: that worked for me, I am using windows os! Can anybody explain how it worked?

Answer (score 12):

Go to Finder > Applications > Android Studio:

1. Right click and click "Show package contents"
2. Create a new folder called `jre`
3. Copy the contents of the `jbr` folder and paste them into the `jre` folder

Answer (score 12):

In latest version of Flutter for Mac, you won't find jre folder under `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents`

Therefore, you can start Terminal and run following commands to fix the issue:

`cd /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents`

`ln -s jbr jre` (creates a symbolic link (shortcut) named `jre` pointing to `jbr`)

If you're on latest version of Mac, you might see error while trying to make changes under Applications folder using Terminal, resolve it by adding `sudo`, like this:

`sudo ln -s jbr jre` (runs the above command as admin, it will ask you for Mac password)

You might still see security alert, then you must go to `System Settings > Privacy & Security > App Management` and `Terminal` as in the list of apps allowed to make changes under Applications folder.

Answer (score 11):

**For Android Studio Preview**

I already install

- Android Studio Preview
- JDK via Android Studio Preview
- Xcode v12 on MacOS 10.15

Here is what I faced `[!] Android Studio: Unable to find bundled Java version.`

Solution:

1. Find out JDK PATH. Check [this](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#what-is-usrlibexecjava-home)

```
#check bash or zsh

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

#return the path of java_home 
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
```

2.Add JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile for bash or .zshenv for zsh

```
$ nano ~/.bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

3.Link JDK path to Android Studio Preview

```
$ cd /Applications/Android\ Studio\ Preview.app/Contents

# flutter doctor check if Contents/jre exist, link jbr with jre
$ ln -s jbr jre

$ cd jbr
$ ln -s ../jbr jdk
$ ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
```

4.[Optional] if you have Android Studio at the same time, you could follow @Nalawala Murtuza solution. It is permitted for `Android Studio` and `Android Studio Preview` at the same time during check from flutter doctor. Doesn't need to delete Android Studio Preview.

[image]

5.Use `flutter doctor -v` to check

Answer (score 9):

**For Windows**
Go To android studio directory (Default C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio)
remove jre folder
run cmd as administrator

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

mklink /D "jre" "jbr"
```

Answer (score 6):

for Ubuntu 22.04 and android sturdio 2022.1.1

`cd path/to/android-studio`

Just copy jbr directory to jre directory

`cp -r jbr/ jre`

and it will work

[image]

Comment: I tried this and just get "cp: cannot create directory 'jre': Read-only file system".  Tried as sudo too, but get the same thing.  Did you have that too?  How did you get around it?

Comment: my android installation is under `$HOME` directory because it is installed by Jetbrains toolbox app
So a manual installation or using the toolbox could resolve your permission problem

Comment: Thanks.  I had installed Android Studio with snap and that was why the error was coming up.  Installing manually (download and extract etc) I was able to add a symlink no problem, but you could equally copy the folder per above too.

Answer (score 5):

Had this issue of `✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.`
Seems like the issue was with **Android Studio (Beta Version)**

Changed my **Android Studio (Stable Version)** to solve the issue

Here are the `flutter doctor -v` details for each  **Android Studio**

**Beta Android Studio**

```
[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
```

**Stable Android Studio**

```
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
```

Even after this issue persist then

- Check for Java
  `java -version`
  `which java`
- double-check that these are present in your .bashrc or .bash_profile or .zshrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/java"
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Comment: I have both the stable and the beta Android Studio installed, how did you change your Android Studio?

Comment: in Android Studio update your Preview channel to Stable.. https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview#change_your_update_channel

Comment: Thank you for the response but I need to use Beta for m1 mac support, will try once and see.

Comment: Unknown to what could be different for M1 macs.

Comment: Any fix for m1 mac?

Answer (score 5):

Double check the path, solved my problem wrapping the path with quotation marks...

**Before**:

[image]

**After**:

[image]

Comment: This answer would be much better if the text were expressed as text, not an image.  [Images are much harder to use than text, for many reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273).

Answer (score 4):

**Apple Silicon Users Problem Solved!**

First do this: [Flutter Doctor --android-licenses : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708446/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclass)

Then:

1. Make Sure to set Java_Home path in .zshrc using same article already listed here. He explains using the .zshenv but we will edit .zshrc file.

https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#what-is-usrlibexecjava-home

2. Uninstall Java from your system
3. Re-install the M1 Specific Version from Azul. Choose Java 16. Choose ARM 64 bit https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk

**Here's Where I Was Stuck But Finally Found The Fix**

Run these commands:

4. cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
5. ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk jdk
6. flutter doctor -v

Comment: I followed your instructions and nothing changed. I'm on an m1 MBP.

Comment: I am using `Java 11`, and I needed to make one small change to make it work. Currently, it is working when I modify your code like the following:

`ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents Contents`

Answer (score 2):

If it's not related to JAVA_HOME path, then try the following:

- go to path: `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google`
  and delete the old version of AndroidStudioXXX.X folder
- now run `flutter doctor` again.
  it fixes mine.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error this morning, when updated ANDROID STUDIO to new version, so to solve this problem you need to find previous version from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive and setup, it works for me! (sorry, if exists grammatical errors)

Comment: There are many versions out there. Which one did you go to?

Answer (score 1):

I use macos big sur 11.5.1 also have the above situation and have successfully fixed the error:

> Unable to find bundled Java version on Flutter &&
> ! Some Android licenses are not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

CH-0 / 203.7678000 is the version you installed if you have to fix it

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7678000/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre 

sudo ln -s ../jre jdk

sudo ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

flutter doctor --android-licenses

flutter doctor -v
```

Answer (score 1):

For mac users

open andriod studio as follow - when you open android studio, it shows content. Open it as above
[image]

then copy paste jbr to jre as follow above

[image]

java path will automatically set.

i have checked on Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure Java is in your PATH and that JAVA_HOME is defined and pointing to the JDK.  I've had Windows put the JRE in the path instead of the JDK, which leads to all kinds of issues.

Please take a look at your PATH environment variable and remove everything Java related that does not point to the JDK folder.

Oracle has some documentation on how to do this here : [Installing Java and setting JAVA_HOME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were two "Android Studio" folders. One was "Android Studio" and another was "Android Studio1", the "Android Studio1" had the actual app installed and the "Android Studio" folder was empty. Deleting the empty folder and renaming the "Android Studio1" to "Android Studio" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu and used JetBrains Toolbox then just do one thing: Go to the Android Studio directory `/home/shahadat/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.9862592` address path will look like this.

if you do not know how to find out the Android studio path from the JetBrains toolbox or anything else then type `flutter doctor -v` and then check Android Studio Section (Version 2022.2) - The version can vary.

Then just copy the `jbr` directory and rename the directory/folder as `jre`.

Now run `flutter doctor -v`

This works for me.

Answer (score -2):

1.Write the path in quotes i.e flutter config --android-studio-dir "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio".

2.Please check the correct path of android Studio.

3.Do the 1st step and run flutter doctor .

Comment: All of this has already been suggested in other answers.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I recently bought an M1 Macbook and then installed Android Studio with the Jetbrains Toolbox but

This folder doesn't exist

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7583922/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre
```

So I follow what this comment say and now is working just fine
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76215#issuecomment-893512809

1.- Go to Applications folder then right click on your android studio app
2.- click on Show package contents
3.- open a terminal inside jre folder then create the new jdk folder

```
mkdir jdk
```

4.- move the folder Contents into jdk

```
mv Contents jdk
```

After refreshing my terminal, flutter doctor works just fine!

Comment: This will probably break other stuff. Also, it stops working when you update Android Studio

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall Android Studio...

Delete folder $/Program Files/Android

Install Android studio...

$flutter doctor

Answer (score -2):

FYI; This is on an M1 Mac.

0. The summary error just says:

```
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
```

1. The summary also suggested `flutter doctor -v` to get more details. Now I see:

```
[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
```

2. I used Finder to delete `Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app`.
3. `flutter doctor` now happy.

HCI suggestion to `flutter doctor` maintainers: default to "full details" when reporting errors.

Comment: doesn't need to delete Android Studio Preview. You can check my solution

Answer (score -2):

WINDOWS SOLVED (Android studio 2022.1.1)

Go to "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\221.6008.13.2211.9477386" then **copy** the content of jbr and paste the content into jre folder

run doctor again and problem solved

Add Path to enviroment variables if nessary
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\221.6008.13.2211.9477386\jre\bin

Answer based on GAYTH BACCARI post. Thanks

Check if path in the enviorment variables are added for JAVA

Answer (score -2):

**Solution for Mac**

Go to finder and find Android studio:

- right click and click show package contents
- Create a new folder called jre
- copy the contents of the jbr folder and paste them into jre folder
- reload your terminal and type flutter doctor

Chill Pill :)

Answer (score -5):

[image]

I was getting this error when I run `flutter doctor`.

Solution:

- Go to the file "java" following the path where Error is shown.
- Then right click on the file and go to Properties.
- Then Go to permissions and **Check** the box "**Allow executing file as program**".
- Finally, run `flutter doctor` to see `No issues found!`.