# Unable to find bundled Java version

Tags: android, flutter

I am working with flutter and the cmd shows that I have an error when I try to run flutter doctor

This is the [cmd's results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgoSz.png) :

```
   [[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476], locale en-US)
    
    [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
        ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
    [!] Android Studio (version 3.3)
        X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
    [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    [√] VS Code (version 1.40.1)
    [√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: you can try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/68575967/11157840

Answer (score 1):

Two issues from your log here. First, to enable the Android SDK you have to read/accept license agreements. You need to do: **flutter doctor --android-licenses** in terminal (or equiv if not Mac) and then follow the prompts to sign the licenses.

If you haven't set up the Flutter SDK, you can follow the instructions [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#get-sdk) (step 3 shows how to enable Flutter permanently in your path which I strongly recommend. This will allow you to run Flutter commands such as `flutter clean`, `flutter doctor`, etc.).

For the second issue, this is usually a problem with an outdated Android Studio implementation. You can try to delete and re-install Android Studio, or see if you can upgrade it: **Android Studio/Check for Updates**.

Comment: I have fixed the first issue, but the java issue is still on even tho I updated AndroidStudio and re-installed it

Comment: I still have this error : Unable to determine bundled Java version..which I don't know why even tho I have re-installed android studio and my java SDK

Comment: Try following the Android Studio/JDK support here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

Comment: In my case `flutter doctor --android-licenses` gives a bunch of Java errors and I'd done the Android Studio/Check for Updates just an hour or two ago.

Comment: @hippietrail you need to install `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)` from Android SDK > SDK Tools

Comment: I'm almost try all possible solution but nothing work. Only this one work for me. Its from `August 9, 2021`

Check the link for the solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68703869/8555332