# Error on VSCode: Unable to determine bundled Java version

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using VSCode as my IDE. (no Android Studio). When I execute flutter doctor I get the error 'Unable to determine bundled Java version'. Does this affect anything? If it does, how do I fix it? (I have tried fixing the path in environment variables.)

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67845759/2457493

Answer (score -1):

Even if you don't use Android Studio you need Android SDK and Java for flutter to run. Make sure both of them are added to your environment variables. Although Android Studio is not necessary for flutter, just installing it and using VSCode as your IDE makes life a lot easier as it handles a lot of setup for you.