# Flutter Doctor --android-licenses : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to install flutter but it won't let me accept the android license. I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX> flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

I've already uninstalled my current version of Java and clean installed Java 8 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html).

This is what `flutter doctor` returns:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139], locale en-IE)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Answer (score 397, accepted):

Installing **Android SDK Command-line tools** from Android SDK Manager did the job for me.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Tools > SDK Manager
3. From the left choose, Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK
4. Select SDK Tools from the top menu
5. Check Android SDK Command-line tools and click 'apply'.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this fixed it for me on Big Sur

Comment: Fixed it on Windows 10 too.

Comment: For cmdline-tools without Android Studio, call `sdkmanager "cmdline-tools;latest"` in command line instead.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me fix issues in Catalina.

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Firstly check for your JAVA_HOME path under **System Variables** it should be like -->

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2**
(no semi-colon and no \bin)

and add to path (in System Variables)-->
**%JAVA_HOME%\bin**

if still, you are getting any error try this
in Android Studio--> Setting(Appearance & Behavior) -> Android SDK -> check and download **Android SDK Command-line tools**.

restart terminal and try again with
flutter doctor --android-licenses

--> this should do the work.

Answer (score -8):

I got same problem.

Just install **Android Studio**, then problem gone.

Comment: This is not true. The issue is caused by the CL-toole missing as the accepted answer suggests. Android Studio does not install them by default as it seems.