# Flutter doctor --android-licenses not working

Tags: android, cmd, flutter2.0

I have installed `flutter 2` on a windows laptop. When I run `flutter doctor` it works fine but I understand that we have to accept licenses by `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. When I run this command I found below error

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 5 more
```

I don't know about this error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Open your terminal
2. type `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
3. press `y` to accept every license.

original link to the post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements)

UPDATED ANSWER to this POST

Installing Android SDK Command-line tools from Android SDK Manager did the job.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Tools > SDK Manager
3. From the left choose, Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK Select SDK
4. Tools from the top menu Check Android SDK Command-line tools and
5. click 'apply'.

orignal link to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708446/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclass)

Comment: I have followed this above procedure but when I type `flutter doctor --android-licences` I am getting the error which I have stated in question.

Comment: Okay @Harry try this might help to get out of this exception.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708446/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclass

Comment: Thank you. The same procedure is followed. You can answer the question and I will accept your answer.

Comment: @harry updated my orignal post now you can accept this answer :) have a great day .

Comment: If the command line did not show (y/n) please install CMake and install other versions of Command-line tools