# Why Flutter Doctor is not Working as my computer?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test

I ran the Flutter doctor command but it's showing I didn't Install Android Studio.
And Also Showing Android licensee not found like that..The Error is -

```
    C:\Users\Arpan Dey>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.631], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

But I have Already Installed Android Studio and Flutter & Dart Plugin...

Another Problem is When I Run flutter doctor --android-licenses command

Its Showing --

```
C:\Users\Arpan Dey>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 5 more
```

Very Sad--

Also When I Run the Default Flutter App Using an Android emulator in the android studio...It's not running...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708446/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclass Can you refer this ?

Comment: you need Java 1.8 to be installed on your system and remove the one currently installed. The issue will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio and go to SDK Manager. After that explore Appearance & Behaviour > go to Android SDK > Click on SDK Tools and install Android Command Line Tools.

If emulator is not running then check if you have installed Android Emulator and Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in the same SDK Tools.

After that run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. It will work.