# Flutter android licenses error while running flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I got error of android licenses while running `flutter doctor` command Its shows could not found main class ui

here's the Screenshot of console:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708446/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclass

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter run error : You have not accepted the license agreements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your terminal
2. type `flutter doctor--android-licenses` press `y` to
3. accept every license