# Android Studio Arctic Fox gives a Gradle error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, java-home

I was doing some basic stuff with Flutter when I received the Android Studio update Arctic Fox. I just updated. When I ran my app (which was fine before the upgrade) just after the update this error appeared.
[image]

`flutter doctor` output is here.

[image]

java version is

[image]

In the Project Structure in Android Studio I cannot set Java SDK as seen below.

[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter?rq=1) question and so many others on the Internet while trying to fix the issue, I could not find the solution yet.  Can someone help me to fix this please.

Answer (score 5):

This is fixed in the master branch of flutter. For now you can switch to master branch and later moved to stable when the code is merged to stable.

```
flutter channel master # This will switch to master branch.
flutter upgrade # This will upgrade flutter.
```

Due to the JDK folder change in new Arctic Fox, flutter needed this update. After running, you can try `flutter doctor` it should say `No issues found!`.

Comment: I am on master channel. it is shown in the 'Flutter doctor' output

Comment: @NuwanThisara can you please fetch the latest. This is the current out of my flutter doctor.
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.5.0-2.0.pre.113, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @kushverma definitely is helpful but since the master version changes from day to day, it is not stable enough to work on. this issue is also fixed in the "beta" channel which is more stable and is prone to fewer issues. Hope this is helpful to anyone who is having this issue.