# Unable to determine bundled Java version

Tags: flutter

I recently updated my android studio to Arctic fox(2020.3.1) and got the following problem when running "flutter doctor".

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.160], locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    ✗ Unable to determine bundled Java version.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

I have referred to several previous posts but none of them fix my issue.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: here is your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter

Comment: I have already tried this, but it doesn't work in windows.

Comment: Hi here is the solution (working on Windows 10): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973723/flutter-unable-to-determine-bundled-java-version