# Flutter 2: Unable to determine bundled Java version

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

I am using Android Studio under Windows 10 to make run a flutter project, however I have this warning I would like to fix :

```
X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
```

I have already try multiple solutions exposed on Stackoverflow / Git but no ones worked.

Here the settings of my project :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here my flutter doctor :

```
C:\lib\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19042.1165], locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\lib\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (8 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:/Users/[MY_USER]/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:/Users/[MY_USER]/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\[MY_USER]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 92.0.902.84

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Could you provide help please ?

Comment: refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68729690/how-i-can-fix-android-license-status-unknown-in-flutter/68730152#68730152

Comment: Well, C:\Users\[my_user]\.jdks\openjdk-16.0.2 (updated in the SDKs), path set in the env variables : JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2, I don't know how can I check for the build gradle but gradle is up to date, SDK Tools up to date (but I can't install : Android Emmulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor (probably because I don't have AMD), and Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator. So it hasn't not resolved the problem :/

Comment: in windows cmd type java -version. what is the results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So here the action I have done:
Install latest version of jdk: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Install latest version of jre: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html

Go to: C:\Program Files\Android and remove all version of Android Studio

Go to Windows search: Environement Variables > Environement Variables > System Variables and add JAVA_HOME with value the path to your jdk (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2)

Install Android Studio again

Go to file > Project Structure

[image]

Put your JDK path:

[image]

[image]

Go to file > Settings

[image]

Click on Show Package Details and retrograde to 20.1 or 22.2 (not sur for 22.2 but read that for some it works)

[image]

Verify you're on a stable version:

[image]

flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub outdated
flutter doctor -v

and it should be good: • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

Comment: What is this: flutter pub get flutter pub upgrade flutter pub outdated flutter doctor -v?

Answer (score 21):

**Easy Solution**

*For Windows*

1. Go to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`
2. Copy the content of jbr
3. Paste it into jre

Then run `flutter doctor`
You will find the **problem is sloved**

Comment: after i uninstalled all android studios in my device,
I did that and it worked

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 4):

For macOS users,

Open the folder

```
open "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents"
```

create the copy of `jbr` and rename it to `jre`. Both `jbr` and `jre` should be in same location

Then run `flutter doctor` and it should work fine

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Have you select your jdk in files android?
Else, I recommand you to watch this post: [Unable to find bundled Java version on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter?rq=1)

Cordially

Answer (score 1):

Is `JAVA_HOME` env variable set? If not, add it

Answer (score 1):

Solution for windows user

- Download and install Java (https://www.java.com/download/ie_manual.jsp)
  [image]
- After installation finished, Go to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_351 and copy everything inside this folder and paste it to this folder : C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
- Run flutter doctor again

[image]

Comment: This is not a good solution, better is to declare the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable pointing to where java was installed then copy things around which can lead to broken paths. Please, edit your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this solution worked for me, thank you! every other solution referred to a folder called 'jbr' which i do not have on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Location on Mac M2:

> cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents

symbolic link:

> sudo ln -s jbr jre