# Unable to determine bundled Java version Android Studio (version 4.1)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have installed the latest Android Studio and when run (flutter doctor) I got this ... Unable to determine bundled Java version Android Studio (version 4.1)
running on windows 10

[cmd image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TxO8.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter 2: Unable to determine bundled Java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973723/flutter-2-unable-to-determine-bundled-java-version)