# Unable to determine bundled Java version windows 10

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

[i had set the java path also the JAVA_HOME variable is also set. but it is giving me this error. Also, i had reinstall the android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xguoA.jpg)

Comment: This question seems duplicated, Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Java will be installed with android studio in the directory
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
Refer this java path in the android studio project structure