# How to resolve this error Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, build.gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

````
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx1G -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\ilapa\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7\lib\gradle-launcher-6.7.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.```

```* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:51)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:84)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:394)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:244)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:301)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:49)
    ... 22 more
````

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Probably you are using an updated version of Android Studio such as Arctic Fox. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter/68575967#68575967

Comment: i am using the latest version

Comment: Yes, I am having the same problem with each update of Android Studio (in my case I am on a Mac and didn't test on my windows machine but I think it is the same). Check the link.

Comment: i am using windows there is only instruction for mac

Comment: Read it carefully.

Comment: still not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can try Deleting your .gradle file

its usually located at %USER%/.gradle

then you add this line to .gradle/gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

Disabling the firewall (although i allow the ide access) and doing this fixed the issue for me.