# Flutter running problem Error: No named parameter with the name 'anchorPoint'

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-form-builder

I am facing issue when I try to run app on emulator or during creating apk file on flutter project. I tried to delete project, **pub get**, **pub cache clean**, **deleted flutter folder** and installed again. Nothing helps, it gives below error always.

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-7.2.1/lib/src/fields/form_builder_date_time_picker.dart:355:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'anchorPoint'.
      anchorPoint: widget.anchorPoint,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:133:19: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Future<DateTime?> showDatePicker({
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-7.2.1/lib/src/fields/form_builder_date_time_picker.dart:373:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'anchorPoint'.
      anchorPoint: widget.anchorPoint,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart:2413:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Future<TimeOfDay?> showTimePicker({
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildAusgleichDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

my flutter doctor result

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675], locale de-DE)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[!] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.0)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: Have you posted this into the Github project (flutter_form_builder) Issue section? That will be the only way.

Comment: I have the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem like this. I commented all anchorPoint in this widget. /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-7.2.1/lib/src/fields/form_builder_date_time_picker.dart. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the latest update of   flutter_form_builder has some issues. I solved the problem by changing

```
  flutter_form_builder: ^7.0.0
```

to

```
  flutter_form_builder: 7.0.0
```

In other words, I added exactly the 7.0.0 version of flutter_form_builder.

THANK ME IF IT WORKED FOR YOU TOO!

Comment: this worked for me! Can you explain the logic of this edit please?

Comment: Latest version of flutter_form_builder has some bugs, so you have to add a version that you are sure has no issues.  7.0.0 has no issues. if you add ^ on 7.0.0, means you need latest version beginning from 7.0.0 and above. so, it ends up giving you a the latest version that has issues. hence solution for now is 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

you need to add jdk to *JAVAHOME* path in your environment varible
you can add it from here
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#what-is-usrlibexecjava-home

and you can find the solution for you issue here
[Unable to find bundled Java version on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter)