# Android Electric eel Mac M1: Unable to find bundled java version when running flutter doctor -v

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

I am having problems with android studio upon updating to electric eel. This was not a problem before update. I have a Mac M1 and flutter version is `Flutter 3.3.10 • channel stable`

When Running `flutter doctor -v` I get this for the android studio section:

```
Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Electric Eel Unable to find bundled Java version. issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75106727/android-studio-electric-eel-unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For mac users**, just go to where is your android studio installed

if you install android studio using the installer use

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents
```

if using JetBrains toolbox use

```
cd "/Users/ahmedhnewa/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/221.6008.13.2211.9477386/Android Studio.app/Contents"
```

you can go to the settings of the ide and find where it's installed

then just type

```
open .
```

so it will be opened in finder

copy the folder `jbr` and rename it to `jre`

I think the flutter team should look into this so the flutter command line
can know where the bundled JDK is in the new android studio update.

currently, there is no recent update to the flutter tool but after it gets update the issue should be fixed without copying the jbr folder and renaming the copied one to jre

> Edit

**For Linux it's almost the same, just the path of android studio is different, it depend on where and how you installed it, for Windows users**
just right click on the android studio on the desktop and open the file location and
do the exists same thing on all platforms

> Update

**You don't need to do any of this, in the latest version of flutter, it already knows where is the jwk from jbr folder, just update both flutter using:
`flutter upgrade`, and your android studio ide**
so you can delete the `jre` folder since there is no need of it

Answer (score 7):

## For Windows Users

### Step - 1

Install Java JRE (JAVA RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT)

Link
https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

After downloading Click on Install and Change Installation folder any folder you like

### Step - 2

Copy all of this content and **GO TO** Android Studio Installation Path

for-example
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

By default Android Studio has a folder called JRE

go inside **jre** folder and paste everything

If JRE folder in Android Studio has anything inside please delete it before pasting.

### Congratulations Windows User

I was struggling with this for like two days and I search it on YouTube and found nothing everything was one year old so I end up Julia Pak Channel while she had Mac but I got the idea to find a solution for windows (basically copy-pasting idea) and find a link in her description and I saw her content and she does an amazing job to help people

So Major Thanks to her.

If anyone ends up on her beautiful YouTube Channel
Give her a like and Subscribe to show some LOVE

YouTube:- https://www.youtube.com/@Juliapak

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see `Unable to find bundled Java version.` is the problem when running `flutter doctor -v` after updating.

This is the work around I did in terminal:

1. `cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr`
2. `ln -s ../jbr jdk`
3. `ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk`

Then I did this in finder:

1. locate Android Studio
2. right click on Android Studio and click `show package contents'
3. create a new folder and call it jre
4. You'll see a jbr folder, open it and copy its contents
5. paste those contents into the jre folder you created. File structure looks like this now
   [image: After creating jre folder and pasting contents of jbr folder]

Honestly I think this is creating redundancy of some sort, but hey it works! when I run `flutter doctor -v` I now get this for android studio.

```
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
```

I'm sure there are better work arounds but this works for me.

[link to video showing how I solved this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARnVVboHJzc)

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me on my Mac

Navigate to Applications on finder Right Click Android Studio. Select "Show package contents". And then right-click "Contents" and select "New Terminal at Folder". Finally copy and paste this line and press enter.

```
ln -s jbr jre
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much! After upgrading to Android Studio Electric Eel when I check flutter doctor I came across with "unable to find bundled java version" then I saw that and that helped a lot! Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Please consider adding this as a comment instead of an answer

Answer (score 1):

Simple Guide

There is problem with Electric eel
Android Studio App contents after installation is not having jre dir

On Mac What i did:

1. copy the jbr directory available and name it as jre
2. jre directory with contents will resolve this