# flutter doctor --android-licenses not working due to java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am trying to accept flutter doctor --android-licenses but I am getting this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Comment: So it looks that you have java 8 installed (class version 52) but this flutter version requires java 11 ( version 55) so easiest solution would be to update java on your machine.

Comment: I faced the same problem, please help me find a solution

Comment: Maybe there are two java versions installed on your system.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v"YOUR_VERSION")
use this command it will be resolved

Answer (score 12):

I'm on MacOS Ventura. I installed Android Studio today. This is how I solved the problem:

1. Downloaded [JDK19](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-mac)
2. Followed the steps mentioned at this [link](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#what-is-usrlibexecjava-home)
3. Since I'm running Android Studio Electric Eel, opened Terminal and ran this command `cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr`
4. Then ran this command after `ln -s ../jbr jdk`
5. And finally, `ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk`
6. Went to Finder -> Applications -> Android Studio. Right-click Android Studio and select 'Show Package Contents'
7. Created new folder 'jre' in folder 'Contents'
8. Copied contents from the 'jbr' folder to the 'jre' folder
9. Ran `flutter doctor` again
10. Ran `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

I was able to agree to the licenses successfully after.

All the steps are also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter/68575967#68575967) and [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-install-flutter-on-macos-6e65dc592449)

Comment: Checkout out `jenv` for managing java versions.

Comment: This comment worked for me but I only had to do the first two steps; Install JDK 19 and then set JAVA_HOME to $(/usr/libexec/java_home)

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same error, I haven't specify JAVA_HOME env, and flutter used my 1.8 java.

For macOS:
Check your JAVA_HOME env
in terminal with

```
printenv
```

if env not existed, list installed java version

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

choose one and execute

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v"YOUR_VERSION")
```

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**

It turns out there are 2 JDK installed in my environment, you can check by using

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

so after removing the older JDK version, the issue is fixed.

---

Having the same error, although here is my `java --version` output

```
java 19.0.1 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

this happens after I upgrade to flutter 3.7.1

Comment: How did you remove the older JDK version? What commands?

Comment: @pathros, from the `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`, you will find the path to the older JDK version, then just use the `sudo rm -rf <old-jdk-path>` to remove it

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple way to resolve this issue.

- Check java version you installed on your machine. If it is version 8, Installed Android SDK Command-line Tools 8.0 & uninstalled latest version.
  [image]

Comment: this is simplest way...thanks, @Abhay! also, if you cannot see all the versions installed, click the Show Package Details checkbox at the bottom.

Comment: That did not work for me. I kept getting a corrupted SDK error until I manually downloaded and installed JDK 20 and set JAVA_HOME to point to it.

Answer (score 3):

Try This (For Windows)

1. Uncheck Android SDK command-line Tools (latest)
2. Check Android SDK command-line Tools 8.0
3. Click Apply
4. In Windows go to
   “C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools”
   and rename the 8.0 folder to “latest”
5. Run Flutter doctor again.

Comment: Solution worked great. For some additional information for ease: if you are in Android studio, then you go to the more actions -> SDK manager -> and then if you check off "Hide Obsolete Packages" and "Show Package Details" then you should be able to find SDK command-line tools 8.0 in the command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command to see if you have multiple java versions:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

In my case, I had 2 versions on my mac: java 8 and java 19. I followed the official [java website](https://www.java.com/en/uninstall/uninstall_instructions.html#:%7E:text=Windows%20ME-,Click%20Start%2C%20point%20to%20Settings%2C%20and%20then%20click%20the%20Control,with%20the%20Uninstall%2C%20click%20Yes.) to remove my older version:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be when the android studio installed is **Android Studio Electric Eel**

All you have to do is:

1. Follow this link and ddownload - install this jdk https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-mac
2. After installing, goto **Finder -> Applications -> Android Studio. Right-click on Android Studio and select 'Show Package Contents'**
3. Open the **Contents** folder and create new folder and name it **jre**
4. There's a folder named **jbr** open it and copy the folder inside it and paste it into your newly created folder on step 3 (jre).
5. You can now be able to accept the licences by running- **flutter doctor --android-licences**

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Windows the reason was that Flutter searched Android SDK Command-line tools under sdk folder instead of Sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to the problem - by updating the JDK directly and then reinstalling Android Studio. I faced a similar issue initially, i use windows 10 pro and here's how I resolved it:

- Check for updates for Flutter. In my case, I was using version 3.10.6.
- Verify and update the JDK installed on your system. I upgraded from Java 8 to Java 20.0.2.
- Update Android Studio to the latest version. I was previously using Electric Eel and updated to Giraffe.
- Re-download the SDKs. I had initially downloaded them while on the Electric Eel version, and upon updating, I found that the SDKs didn't need to be updated separately. This saved me some time. During the uninstallation of Electric Eel, I didn't delete the SDK cache.
- Run `flutter doctor -v` again and accept android licenses by `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

It's important to note that Flutter only functions with the most up-to-date version of JAVA, which is closely tied to the version of Android Studio you're using.

Answer (score 0):

use `flutter config --jdk-dir PATH_TO_YOUR_NEW_VERSION_JDK_DIR` to set your jdk dir, this works for me