# Flutter Doctor: Android license status unknown

Tags: flutter

while I'm installing flutter on my MacBook with `macOS Ventura` , I got this problem `Android license status unknown` when I run `flutter doctor` .

[image: flutter doctor]

also this when I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

[image: flutter doctor --android-licenses]

Android Version `4.1.2`
Android SDK Version `30.0.2`

I tried to solve the problem by update  `Android SDK Tools` & `Android SDK Command-line Tools` , but still same issues shown.

Comment: did you run the command from inside the bin folder of flutter ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter doctor --android-licenses not working due to java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75328050/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-not-working-due-to-java-lang-unsupportedclassv)