# Android Studio java.io.IOException - Update from Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2 -> Flamingo | 2022.2.1

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

When I tried to update my Android Studio from Electric Eel to Flamingo, after downloading update, and restart android studio for installing this update I got this Error:

[image]

and this is a stored LOG:

```
17/04 11:36:12 INFO  Runner.initLogger - --- Updater started ---
17/04 11:36:12 INFO  Runner._main - args: [install, /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents]
17/04 11:36:12 INFO  Runner._main - destination: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents), case-sensitive: false
17/04 11:36:14 INFO  Utils.getTempFile - created a working directory: /Users/<usr>/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1/tmp/patch-update/idea.updater.files.12145042962668282155
17/04 11:36:14 INFO  Runner.install - Extracting patch file...
17/04 11:36:14 INFO  Utils.getZipEntry - entryPath: patch-file.zip
17/04 11:36:16 INFO  Utils.getZipEntry - entryPath: .patch-info
17/04 11:36:16 INFO  PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate - Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2 -> Flamingo | 2022.2.1
17/04 11:36:16 INFO  Patch.forEach - Validating installation... [5271 actions]
17/04 11:36:16 ERROR Runner.install - prepare failed
java.io.IOException: An absolute link: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin -> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestRegularFile(Digester.java:50)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.digestFile(Patch.java:450)
    at com.intellij.updater.DeleteAction.validate(DeleteAction.java:42)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$validate$0(Patch.java:292)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:438)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.validate(Patch.java:291)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate(PatchFileCreator.java:109)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:413)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner._main(Runner.java:221)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:49)

17/04 11:36:32 INFO  Runner.cleanup - Cleaning up...
17/04 11:36:32 INFO  Utils.tryDelete - deleted: /Users/<usr>/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1/tmp/patch-update/idea.updater.files.12145042962668282155/patch.tmp.0
17/04 11:36:32 INFO  Utils.tryDelete - deleted: /Users/<usr>/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1/tmp/patch-update/idea.updater.files.12145042962668282155
17/04 11:36:32 INFO  Utils.cleanup - deleted a working directory: /Users/<usr>/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1/tmp/patch-update/idea.updater.files.12145042962668282155
17/04 11:36:32 INFO  Runner.refreshApplicationIcon - refreshApplicationIcon for: /Applications/Android Studio.app
```

also I tried this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68575967/9133703

---

but it is not fixed my problem

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
```

[image]

---

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr
```

[image]

---

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre
```

[image]

---

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Right-click on the /Applications/Android Studio.app and then click  "Show Package Content". What do you see in it?

Comment: @arg0nath
the "contents" and then in contents:

_CodeSignature/
bin/
CodeResources
Info.plist
jbr/
jre/
lib/
license/
MacOS/
plugins/
Resources/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I tried to delete both
`JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` links
from

`/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre`

and

`/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr`

the problem fixed.