# Android Studio JDK version not changing on mac. Why? How can I fix it?

Tags: java, android, flutter, java-11

Hello I am on mac and I changed the sdk version as many tutorials say. If I run `java --version` I get this:

```json
openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.19+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.19+0, mixed mode)
```

The problem is when I run `flutter doctor --verbose` I get this on android studio:

```bash
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
```

The JDK versions are different. And when I try to run a flutter project I get this error:

```bash
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @52a71430
```

**Additional information**:

- When I open my flutter project by the android folder in android
  studio I can configure `project settings` and select the jdk version.
- This works only if I run the app inside the android folder in android
  studio. If I run it from the root it throws the same error.
- The command output of `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` is this:

```bash
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    11.0.19 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 11.0.19" /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.19/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.19/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

- In my ~/.zshrc I have an export of `export JAVA_HOME='/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.19/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home'`

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm stuck at the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to change the version that flutter doctor -v shows doing the following, i deleted the android folder from my User location, deleted the android studio i had wich was the flamingo version and installed the Electric eel version from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive then i followed this instructions For the JetBrains Runtime "Android Studio Electric Eel"
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr
ln -s ../jbr jdk
ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
Then go to the Finder and search for Android Studio:

Right click -> Show Package Contents
Open the contents folder, then create new folder called jre
Copy the contents of the JetBrainsRuntime folder and paste it into the jre folder from the answer [Unable to find bundled Java version on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter) and finally my flutter doctor -v shows java version 11 that allowed me to compile the flutter project, hope this helps!