# Flutter Doctor (2022.3 version) Reporting Android Studio Flutter Plugin Not Installed

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I ran `flutter doctor` and can't seem to solve these problems

```
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
```

**Android studio version**

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996, built on June 29, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    Dart (223.8950)
    io.flutter (75.1.2)
```

**My mbp info**

Apple M2
13.4 (22F66)

**My question**

I have searched for many solutions and tried them, but none of them have solved my problem. I hope someone knowledgeable can help me with this issue. Thank you.

What I've tried so far, which hasn't worked:

```
$ cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents
$ ln -s jbr jre
ln: jre/jbr: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the first two issues, just install the Dart and Flutter plugins in Android Studio as listed [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/editor?tab=androidstudio).

For the Java issue, it looks like a permission issue. Try running with `sudo` as the bottom of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75119315/9063935) answer suggests. If that doesn't work, it may be that your terminal doesn't have permissions for that directory. See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345142/447859) answer to give it permissions.